# Ассемблер TASM переизбыток кода

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Столкнулся с проблемой, связаной с TASM: имеется основной файл программы (291 строка) и подключаемый модуль с макросами (370 строк). Если попытаться добавить еще код в основной модуль, то программа перестает работать корректно. Происходит трансляция и линковка без проблем, но дальнейшая логика ломается (при вызове функции программа переходит по неверному адресу), даже если добавлена "пустышка" (5 раз push ax, 5 раз pop ax). Изменение модели памяти не привели ни к чему.
Программа отрабатывает стабильно верно до этого, но если добавить новую процедуру (при этом даже не вызывать ее), то программа начинает ломаться.
Заранее всем спасибо за помощь.

```
include hw5INC.inc
.286
.MODEL small
.386
.stack 4000
.data
;ntes dw 0;
;tes db 1h;
;==================================
;          MENU INIT
;==================================
;         DESCRIPTIONS
;==================================
matPrtD db '[1] Print matrix$'; 
matFllD db '[2] Fill matrix$'; 
maxValD db '[3] Find max value$';
;==================================
select db '[0] Exit$';, 10, 13, 
select2 db ' >>> $';
new_line db 10, 13, '$';
err_msg db 'Input error!', 10, 13, '$';
desc dw (offset matPrtD), (offset matFllD)
el_ctr db ($-desc)/4;
labels dw (offset matPrtF), (offset matFllF)
;len dw 0;
len dw $ - labels;
row_ctr db 10;
;==================================

buff db 10 dup(0);
bsize db 4;
res dw 0;

ti dw 0;
tj dw 0;
rows dw 2;
cols dw 3;
matrix dw 1, 2, -3, 4, 5, -6;
matFllMsg db 'Input matrix rows and collumns counters:', 10, 13, '$';
matFllELZ db 'Error: values must be greater than zero!', 10, 13, '$';
matFllETH  db 'Error: values is too high!', 10, 13, '$';
matFllIMsg db 'Input matrix values value by value', 10, 13, '$';

maxVal dw 0;
tmp dw 0;

.code
;==================================
;           FUNCTIONS
;==================================
matPrtF proc
    set_cursor 0, 0; 
    mat_print matrix, rows, cols, ti, tj; mat, rows, cols, ti, tj
    ret;
matPrtF endp

matFllF proc
    set_cursor 0, 0; 
    
    matFllFBeg:
    print matFllMsg;
    stoi buff, bsize, cols; fill rows counter
    ;itos rows;
    cmp cols, 0; 0 < rows < 20
    jle matFllLower0;
    cmp cols, 20;
    jge matFllGreater;
    
    stoi buff, bsize, rows; fill cols counter
    ;itos cols;
    cmp rows, 0; 0 < cols < 20
    jle matFllLower0;
    cmp rows, 20;
    jge matFllGreater;
    jmp matFllFill;
    matFllLower0:
        print matFllELZ; print error msg Lower Than Zero
        jmp matFllFBeg;
    
    matFllGreater:
        print matFllETH; print error msg Greater Than [20]
        jmp matFllFBeg;
    ;fill matrix values
    matFllFill:
    print matFllIMsg;
    mat_fill matrix, rows, cols, buff, bsize, res;matrix, rows, cols, buff, bsize, res;
    ret;
matFllF endp


;maxVF proc
    ;max_row_el matrix, tmp, cols, maxVal;
    ;itos maxVal;
    ;mov cx, rows;
    ;max_while_start:
    ;   dec cx;
    ;   mov tmp, cx;
    ;   inc cx;
    ;   max_row_el matrix, tmp, cols, maxVal;
    ;   itos maxVal;
    ;   loop max_while_start_end;
    ;max_while_start_end:
;   ret
;maxVF endp


;==================================
;          MENU FUNCTIONS
;==================================
cursor_move proc
    push ax;
    push dx;
    push bx;
    mov ah, 02h;
    mov dh, row_ctr;
    mov dl, 30;
    ;add dh, cl;
    mov bh, 00h;
    int 10h;
    pop bx;
    pop dx;
    pop ax;
    ret
cursor_move endp;

clear_screen proc;
    
    ;mov row_ctr, 10;
    push ax;
    push bx;
    push cx;
    push dx;
    xor ax, ax;
    mov al, 10;
    sub al, el_ctr;
    mov row_ctr, al;
    mov ax, 0600h;
    mov bh, 09h;
    mov cx, 0000;
    mov dx, 184Fh;
    int 10h;
    pop dx;
    pop cx;
    pop bx;
    pop ax;
    ret
clear_screen endp;

fun_print proc ; bx -> func address
    push ax;
    push dx;
    push bx;
    call clear_screen;
    mov ah, 02h;
    mov dh, row_ctr;
    sub dh, el_ctr;
    mov dl, 30;
    ;add dh, cl;
    
    mov bh, 00h;
    int 10h;
    
    call bx;
    
    mov ah, 07h;
    int 21h;
    pop bx;
    pop dx;
    pop ax;
    ret
fun_print endp

print_menu proc
    push ax;
    push bx;
    push dx;
    push cx;
    call clear_screen;
    ;mov ax, 0600h;
    ;mov bh, 07h;
    ;mov cx, 0000;
    ;mov dx, 184h;
    ;int 10h;
    ;mov ah,2
    ;mov bh,0
    ;mov dx,1800h
    ;int 10h
    mov cl, row_ctr;
    mov ah, 09h;
    mov di, 0;
    mov bx, offset desc;
    mov dx, offset new_line;
    ;int 21h;
    print_while:
        mov dx, [bx + di];
        call cursor_move;
        int 21h;
        add di, 2;
        inc cl;
        mov row_ctr, cl;
        ;inc row_ctr;
        cmp di, len;
        jae print_while_end;
        jmp print_while;
    print_while_end:
    mov dx, offset select;
    ;inc cl;
    call cursor_move;
    int 21h;
    
    mov dx, offset select2;
    inc cl;
    mov row_ctr, cl;
    call cursor_move;
    int 21h;
    inc cl;
    mov row_ctr, cl;
    ;mov row_ctr, cl;
    pop cx;
    pop dx;
    pop bx;
    pop dx;
    ret;
print_menu endp;

;==================================
;            MAIN
;==================================
main proc
    mov ax, @data;
    mov ds, ax;
    xor ax, ax;
    ;xor bx, bx;
    ;movzx bx, tes;
    ;mov ax, bx;
    ;mov ax, offset len;
    ;sub ax, offset labels;
    ;mov len, ax;
    ;mov cx, len;
    ;mov bx, n_len;
    ;xor bx, bx;
    xor cx, cx;
prog_start:
    call print_menu;
    xor ax, ax;
    xor dx, dx;
    mov cl, '1';
    mov di, 0;
    mov ah, 01h;
    int 21h;
    mov ah, 09h;
    mov dx, offset new_line;
    int 21h;
    cmp al, '0';
    je while_end;
while_start:
    cmp cl, al;
    je m_call;
    add di, 2;
    inc cl;
    cmp di, len;
    jae m_err;
    jmp while_start;
m_call:
    mov bx, [offset labels + di];
    
    ;push ax;
    ;push cx;
    ;mov cx, 3;
    ;call cursor_move;
    ;call clear_screen;
    ;call bx;
    call fun_print;
    ;mov ah, 07h;
    ;int 21h;
    ;pop cx;
    ;pop ax;
    jmp prog_start;
m_err:
    mov dx, offset err_msg;
    mov ah, 09h;
    int 21h;
    jmp prog_start;
while_end:
    
    mov ax, 4c00h;
    int 21h;
    ret;
main endp
;==================================
end main;
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Смотрите адреса условных переходов в коде - они должны быть в пределах 128-байт вперёд/назад. На безусловные `jmp/call` это ограничение не действует. Если-же модулей/процедур много, то загружайте их в пространство программы как оверлеи.

Comment: Благодарю! Разобрался данной проблемой, оказалось, что один из скриптов действительно совершал слишком длинный переход.